# Как сделать так чтобы display: table-cell был адаптивным

Tags: css, html5, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Привет всем, дорогие друзья.

Предо мной стоит интересная задача, мне необходимо сделать адаптивность, прописываю `max-width` для каждого отдельного контейнера, и задаю максим `width:100%`, 
у меня значит `<div id="left">` и `<div id="right">`каждый поделен CSS свойствами на `display: table-cell`, и если использую `display:block` то весь, контейнер становится не красивым и не адаптивным.

Как мне быть ?

Comment: Код добавите? Так будет проще.

Answer (score 3):

При отсутствии (на данный момент) кода в вопросе можно ответить только так:

Чтобы сохранялась адаптивность при использовании `display: table-cell` , у родительского элемента должен стоять `display: table`.

Answer (score 0):

Потратьте время на изучение "display: flexbox" и вы будете удивлены его возможностями :)

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
</div>


.container {
 border: 2px solid #ffffff;
 padding: 20px;
 display: flex;
 }

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```